# Using EPPlus, how do I return a cell value as it has been formatted by Excel?

Tags: excel, epplus

I use EPPlus to load an Excel file that has numeric cells having this special format:

```
00"."00"."00"."000"."0
```

Hence, a cell value of `123456789` is displayed on Excel as `01.23.45.678.9`

It's a sort of a material coding standard. Now, I would like to use EPPlus to return the formatted value in a string. I am not really interested in the numeric value. Also, I don't want to do the formatting manually in my code because the number format may sometimes vary. How would I do this?

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know if you can get to the Excel Object Model from EPPLUS, but if you can, then retrieve something like: **Range("A1").Text** .......this gets the "as formatted" cell contents.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks for your response. I am not sure if you mean a Range other than the ExcelRange I obtain through `myWorksheet.Cells["A1"]`, but the Text property of this ExcelRange returns the numeric value not the formatted contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue in EPPlus. (**update**: I filed [an issue](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15041).)

If you run your example with EPPlus under a debugger, you'll see that EPPlus is producing the string value from ExcelRangeBase.cs:965 using the expression `d.ToString(format, nf.Culture)` where `d` is the converted double value of your cell's text, `format` is `"00.00.00.000.0"`, and `nf` is an EPPlus `ExcelFormatTranslator` (but the latter is not important to this particular issue).

The issue is that an un-literalized `.` in a custom numeric format string is taken to be a decimal point. So the value of `format` at this point in the EPPlus code should be `"00'.'00'.'00'.'000'.'0"`.

I'm not yet sure what would be the best fix for this, but it looks to require a change somewhere in `ExcelNumberFormatXml.ExcelFormatTranslator.ToNetFormat`.

In the meantime, you don't have to do the formatting manually in your own code. Before calling the `Text` property, you can set the number format to what it should be, e.g.:

```
range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "00'.'00'.'00'.'000'.'0";
```

Now `range.Text` should give you the string you were expecting.

Comment: That was a real life saver. Thanks @billisphere for the great help :)